# Why does Python return (2, False, 3) instead of True for a, b == 2, 3?

Tags: python

When running this code :

```
a=2
b=3
a,b==2,3
```

I expected Python to return `True`.

Instead, I get `(2, False, 3)`

What can possibly be the reason?
[Original post](https://twitter.com/dabeaz/status/1387085343468441600?s=20)

Comment: `a , (b==2), 3` that is how it works, precedence

Comment: Since Python thought you are creating a tuple of `(a, b== 2, 3)`, which results in `(2, False, 3)`

Comment: You can try something like `(a,b)==(2,3)` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last line does not evaluate as a functional expression, but rather a tuple of variables:

```
# a=2
# b=3
a, b==2, b 
# evaluates to:
tuple(a, "does b equal 2?", b)
```

As `b` does not equal (the previously assigned) `3`, the second element in the tuple is False:

```
tuple(2, False, 3)
```

---

To perform a comparison we can write this:

```
# items = a, b==2, b 
is_match = (a,b) == (2,3) 
# True
```

Due to the parenthesis, `(a,b)` and `(2,3)` are two tuples - of which we then equate.

Answer (score 1):

If the third line is written as
`a,    b==3,    4`
I would have got it instantly.
Took me a minute to re-parse that.
Operator precedence can be a silent killer!
I tried to make it even more evil, but parens-less comma operator is not supported in many scenarios.

```
x = a, b == 3, 4  # no

bool(a, b == 3, 4) # no

True if a, b == 3, 4 else False # no
```

The correct way to do that is :

```
>>> a = 2
>>> b = 3
>>> (a, b) == (2, 3)
True
```